# How could I add an entry to the right click menu?

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, menu

I'm not really sure how to google this one . I would like to know how would I add an entry to the right click menu in a Windows system . Something like "Open with ..." or "Archive with ... " . I would preffer a solution that works under Windows XP .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in the registry, HKEY CLASSES ROOT houses the stuff you need.

specifically

```
(any file)
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers 

(any folder)
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
```

The old nvidia rightclick on desktop feature would remove the "new" from folders when you uninstalled the driver. So I had to figure out how to restore it.

Good luck.